# Data migration assistant showing breaking changes/ behaviour changes for SQL 2019 but not for Azure SQL Managed instance

Tags: migration, azure-vm, azure-sql-managed-instance

I am trying to assess the potential issues while migrating a SQL Server 2012 on-prem database to Azure, with **SQL on Azure VM** and **Azure SQL Managed instance** as targets.

For SQL on Azure VM, DMA is showing few breaking changes and behavior changes (screenshot below)
[image: DMA assessment for SQL on Azure VM]
DMA assessment for SQL on Azure VM

But, for Azure SQL managed instance there are no compatibility issues seen. Is this expected? I was wondering why the behavior and syntax issues will be shown for Azure SQL VM and not in managed instance. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: I'm skeptical that MI would support something that 2019 doesn't. However, you'll need to [edit] your question to add in details on details as to what object/syntax is throwing that error, so that any answer can be definitive.